# Linear maps: Do this functions produce a linear map

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to know if there exists a linear map $$A: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow P_{\mathbb{R}}^{2}$$

with

$$A(1,2,3) = x^2 -1$$
$$A(0,2,1) = 3x + 4$$
$$A(-1,0,-2) = x^2+x+1$$

Is there any possibility to show it? I hope you can help me!

Comment: Isn't the domain of $A$ $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Comment: That is right. I corrected it.

Comment: What is $L$ in $L(-1,0,-2)$? Shouldn't it be $A$?

Comment: Yes, right. It should be A

Answer (score 1):

Hint: the three vectors for which an image is specified satisfy a linear dependence relation (their alternating sum is zero). Do the specified images satisfy the same relation? Conclude.

Comment: Do you mean I shall simply sum up the three vectors and the result has to be zero? $$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0\\2\\1
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\0\\-2
\end{pmatrix} = \vec{0}$$ Is that right?

Comment: Do you mean I shall simply sum up the three vectors and the result has to be zero? $$\begin{pmatrix}
1\\2\\3
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
0\\2\\1
\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}
-1\\0\\-2
\end{pmatrix} = \vec{0}$$ Is that right? My result is $$\begin{pmatrix}
0\\4\\2
\end{pmatrix}$$ But I guess that is not correct. Don't I need the second parts of my functions? Or do I have to sum up $$(x^2 -1 )+(3x + 4)+(x^2 + x + 1) = 0$$

Comment: An _alternating_ sum has alternating signs $+v_1-v_2+v_3-v_4+\cdots$. A linear dependence relation involves arbitrary coefficients (but not all zero): $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+\cdots=0$. You should have learned how in general one finds whether such a linear dependence relation between given vectors exists; my sentence was just quick a hint about the outcome for these particular vectors, but you should be able to find it without the hint.

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to make Marc's answer less cryptic.

If $A$ is linear, then we must have that $A(0,0,0)=\mathbf{0}$, where $\mathbf{0}$ is the zero polynomial.

But in your case, notice that your vectors $v_1, v_2, v_3$ satisfy $$v_2-v_1=v_3$$Therefore $$-v_1+v_2-v_3=(0,0,0)$$
So we must have $$A(-v_1+v_2-v_3)=A(0,0,0)=\mathbf{0}$$
But if $A$ is linear, then we must also have $$A(-v_1+v_2-v_3)=-A(v_1)+A(v_2)-A(v_3)=-(x^2-1)+(3x+4)-(x^2+x+1)$$
Is this the zero polynomial?

Comment: The result of your equation is $$-2x^2+2x+4$$ and therefore it is not the zero polynomial. Thus I can say it does not exist a linear map with these vectors. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's right...